# Retrieve all members in object class in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

An Object is given:

```
object ObjectA{
    val member1 = ClassX(...)
    val member2 = ClassX(...)
}
```

Is it possible to get access to all members dynamically? I would like to iterate through all of them to avoid tons of the same code.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the [documentation on reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). But note that usage of reflection has its drawbacks (lack of typesafety, ability to access private members, performance).

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This smells like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps explain what you're trying to *achieve* instead of asking *how to* do something specific.

Comment: this is exactly what i want to achieve :D. ObectA is inside a given package which maintenance is not in my hands. I would like to have a validation to check every single of its members without knowing that object exactly. The members however are not final. New members could be added or existing once could be removed. Thats why i was thinking to get them dynamically. Reflections seems to be the right way. At least for this architecture.